# Proving that $|\{B\subseteq S: |B|<\infty \}|=|S|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I've some elementary set theory problem that I came across with:

Let $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be infinite set, and let $A=\{B\subseteq S: |B|<\infty \}$. I'm interested in showing that cardinality of set $A$ is equals to cardinality of $S$, i.e $|A|=|S|$.

I thought using *Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem* in some way.

Comment: $A$ is a set of subsets of $S$ ($\mathbb R$), while $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$, so $A\subseteq S$ can't be true.

Comment: .........Right!

Comment: @Ragnar: There are sets which are equal to the set of their finite subsets. That is, $X=\{Y\subseteq X\mid Y\text{ finite}\}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**
What is the cardinality of the set of singleton subsets of $S$?

What is the cardinality of the set of two-element subsets of $S$?

$\cdots$

What is the cardinality of the set of $n$-element subsets of $S$?

$\cdots$

Comment: Not the asker but this had bugged me: how do you prove that $|S\times S|=|S|$??? I have difficulty finding whatever theorem that is needed for this. (did not study set theory)

Comment: We need Axiom of Choice for that." $|S\times S|=|S|$ for any infinite set $S$ " is an equivalent statement to AC.

Comment: Ah, can you tell me the name of the theorem though? Or a reference. Seems like Google only come up the the countable case.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_theorem

Comment: Thanks, but what about the other direction? (ie. AoC implies $|A|=|A\times A|$)

Comment: The other direction will be easy one: consider a well-order in a set $A$, and construct bijection between the two sets.

Comment: Ah sorry I have not done set theory, I can't quite figure out how to do that. Can you give me a reference, if it is long to prove?

Comment: @Gina: I have written several answers about Tarski's theorem.

Comment: @Gina See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54892/about-a-paper-of-zermelo/) and other questions linked there.

Comment: @Gina: Not every easily understandable statement has an easily understandable proof. One can prove that $|A|=|A\times A|$ using Zorn's lemma, but you still have to understand what is "transfinite induction" (on the class of cardinals), http://math.stackexchange.com/a/608555/622

Comment: @AsafKaragila:thanks for the link. Sorry I just thought that this is an elementary set theory question, so the answer to the question shouldn't be that hard. And the proof of $|A|=|A\times A|$ is needed to answer the question, at least for $|A|\leq 2^{\aleph_{0}}$.

Comment: @Gina: If only... one can arrange models where the axiom of choice fails, and there are infinite sets of real numbers with $|A|<|A\times A|$.